# Iterating over a collection with 'const_iterator' in a function declared 'const' results in an error

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, constants, deque

This method:

```
void LRU::displayQueue() const
{
   for(iter = m_buffer.begin(); iter != m_buffer.end(); ++iter)
      std::cout << (*iter) << " ";
   std:: cout << std::endl;
}
```

results in the following error:

```
lru.cpp:58: error: passing 'const std::_Deque_iterator<int, const int&, const int*>' as    'this' argument of 'std::_Deque_iterator<int, const int&, const int*>& std::_Deque_iterator<int, const int&, const int*>::operator=(const std::_Deque_iterator<int, const int&, const int*>&)' discards qualifiers
```

`m_buffer` and `iter` are declared in my header file, where the buffer is declared as a `deque` of type `int` and `iter` is a constant iterator:

```
// ...

std::deque<int> m_buffer;
std::deque<int>::const_iterator iter;

// ...
```

Removing the `const` in the `displayQueue` method will eliminate the compiler error, but since this function shouldn't modify any data in the `deque`, I want to make this explicit by keeping my code "const-correct". Why would this result in an error, when my iterator is a  `const_iterator`?

Comment: Is `iter` a member of `LRU`? If so, then that is a problem.

Comment: Is `iter` is `LRU` class member? If so you cannot modify it in const function unless you declare it `mutable`.

Comment: try cbegin() and cend() to get a const iterator.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious:  That's not the problem here.

Comment: That was a small "derp" moment for me. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're modifying the object by setting the value of your const iterator member variable, thus invalidating the const restriction of your function. Use a local variable.

A `const_iterator` only means the iterator cannot modify the sequence, but you're not modifying the sequence, you modifying the member variable iterator *itself*.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot modify any members of a class in a `const` member method, and that's what you're trying to do here:

```
for(iter = m_buffer.begin();iter != m_buffer.end(); ++iter)
    ^^^^^^^                                         ^^^^^^
```

`iter` is a member of `class LRU`, so you can't assign, increment or otherwise change it in a `const` member function.

One solution would be to make `iter` mutable:

```
mutable std::deque<int>::const_iterator iter;
```

But my feeling is most uses of `mutable` are an indication of a design flaw.  In this case, I'd suspect that having `iter` be a member of `class LRU` in the first place is a potential design flaw.  Why would you need/want this?

So, instead of making `iter` a `mutable` member, I'd first consider not having it be a member at all and use a local variable instead.

Answer (score 2):

Because your member function is a const, which means you promise not to change any members in this function. Well, iter is a member and you are trying to change it in the function, so there is the error.

Answer (score 1):

In a const object of type `LRU`, the `iter` member is const, so you can't modify it in that loop. You need to make a separate copy of it. That's why standard library algorithms take iterator objects: so they can modify the iterator objects to move through the sequence, even if there's an underlying container object that's const.

Answer (score 1):

```
void LRU::displayQueue() const
{
  // std::_Deque_iterator<int, const int&, const int*> l_iter = m_buffer.begin();
  for(auto l_iter = m_buffer.begin(); l_iter != m_buffer.end(); ++l_iter)
    std::cout << (*l_iter) << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

should work. As other people said, a const value cannot be modified. The `begin()` method on the `Deque` class is overloaded to return const or non const values, and in this case it would pick up the non const one. Alternatively, you could explicitely denote the type of iter as not being const.

Comment: Yes, this should work, but it does not explain what the problem is or why this fixes it.  It also introduces a potential new problem:  name hiding.

Comment: what type will `auto` deduce in this case?